# Python Class Instance Scope (& VS Code Autocomplete)

Tags: python, oop, autocomplete

I am migrating a project I have from being littered with `globals` to actually have a structure defined by classes defined in a separate module. This is my first time really using OOP so want to make sure that I am understanding scope correctly as my Python editor of choice (VS Code) isn't doing autocomplete / Intellisense correctly.

At the top of my code, I import my module -

```
import NHLGameEvents
```

I create my object in the **main** section of code -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_info = is_game_today()

    # Create a Game Object
    gameobj_game_type = game_info["gameType"]
    gameobj_date_time = game_info["gameDate"]
    gameobj_game_state = game_info["status"]["abstractGameState"]
    gameobj_venue = game_info["venue"]["name"]
    gameobj_live_feed = game_info["link"]

    gameobj_broadcasts = {}
    gameobj_broadcasts[broadcast_team] = broadcast_channel
    game = NHLGameEvents.Game(gameobj_game_type, gameobj_date_time, gameobj_game_state,
                              gameobj_venue, gameobj_live_feed, gameobj_broadcasts)
```

I then have a method where I want to log some properties of that method -

```
def get_game_events():
    logging.info("Getting data from endpoint: %s", game.live_feed)
    live_feed_json = requests.get(game.live_feed).json()
    return live_feed_json
```

I have two questions about the above code -

1. In my `get_game_events()` method, should I be able to access `game.live_feed` given the scope in which it was defined? My code executes correctly, but I am not getting autocomplete once I type the `game.` statement.
2. If I am supposed to define the objects within a separate method such as `main()` - how do I ensure that other methods within my code can access those class instances?

Comment: Where is `get_game_events` defined?  How does it know about `game` at all?

Comment: The `get_game_events` method is defined at the top of the script I am writing -- where I import the `NHLGameEvents` module & all of the above code is contained. My understanding was that if `game = NHLGameEvents.Game(...)` was not contained within a method, then it was part of the global scope and could be referenced anywhere else. That was part of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question. Do you mean, how to access variables declared in __init__?

Comment: Yes, `game` as you defined it is in global scope.  I'm a bit confused because I thought you said you were trying to get *rid* of globals! :-)  Anyway, I don't know how VS does its autocompletion.

Comment: @BrenBarn I meant the **global** keyword more than anything, but if my object is defined within a separate method, how do I ensure that other methods have access to it - do I have to pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: @mattdonders: Basically, yes.  The idea is that you don't ensure that "other methods" in general have access to it.  You pass to each function the objects that it needs.  Or you write a class and write methods on it.  What you're calling a "method" looks like it's probably actually a standalone function.

Comment: @JPYamamoto let's say I don't define `game` at the module level, but instead do it in a separate method (called `main()` or `create_game_object()` or whatever) - how do I ensure that other methods in my code, such as `get_game_events()` has access to that instance - do I have to pass it around via an argument to the function?

Comment: @BrenBarn wasn't sure the differentiation in Python between a method & a function. I guess you are saying if I have a standalone function, then I should give it all of the information it needs (via passed arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should point out that functions are the ones declared with `def` while a method, is similar to a function, but it lives inside a class.

1-Yes, it is supposed to be able to access game. In python you can access variables in an upper level, as long as you are not changing its value. If you set the value of a variable inside a function it will be accessible only inside that function.

```
a = 1

def my_function():
    print(a) # Prints 1 when called
    a = 2
    print(a) # Prints 2 when called

print(a) # Prints 1
```

However, I suggest you always pass the values you will need inside a function as an argument. Is cleaner, and avoids side effects by removing the global scope.

2-You can't access the values of a function from another function, regardless it's called `main` or some other name. However, you can access the values of a function from another function as long as the second is inside the first. For example:

```
def first_function():
    a = 1
    def second_function():
        print(a) # Prints 1

def my_function():
    prints(a) # Error, because 'a' does not exist in this scope.
```